# SQL with two DISTINCT Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Created_by",
                SUM (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.NO_OF_LINES_PROCESSED),
                CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.TYCO_CALENDAR_MONTH_NM,
                CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.TYCO_CALENDAR_YEAR_ID,
                CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Source_ID"
  FROM CCO.CSSC_MASTER_VIEW CSSC_MASTER_VIEW
 WHERE     (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Created_by" = 'TE160961')
       AND (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.TYCO_CALENDAR_MONTH_NM = 'JULY')
       AND (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.TYCO_CALENDAR_YEAR_ID = 2013)
       AND (CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Source_ID" = '10')
GROUP BY CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Created_by",
         CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.NO_OF_LINES_PROCESSED,
         CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.TYCO_CALENDAR_MONTH_NM,
         CSSC_MASTER_VIEW.TYCO_CALENDAR_YEAR_ID,
         CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Source_ID"
```

This query returns NO_OF_LINES_PROCESSED is 199 which is absolutely right.
Here comes the problem when i try to Join this statement with another table.

I have another table by name CSSC_QUALITY_DATA which has the field "Created_by" and other fields. When i create join between this field and CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Created_by", the NO_OF_LINES_PROCESSED returns does not match with my first result of 199.

Here i know the cause for this. The second table has multiple "Created_by" fields. How can i establish a relationship between these two tables

Comment: Please edit your question, paste the query again, then select the text of the query using the mouse and click on a `code sample {}` icon at top of the editor window to make the query readable.

Comment: Thanks for the information kordirko. I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need an ON clause on the JOIN, something like this :

```
JOIN CSSC_QUALITY_DATA ON CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Created_by" =  CSSC_QUALITY_DATA."Created_by"
```

Finally to avoid the distinct put everything you need to be distinct in the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
GROUP BY CSSC_MASTER_VIEW."Created_by",
         CSSC_QUALITY_DATA."Created_by",
```

In this way you can avoid the use of the distinct and achieve the same desired result with the Group BY .

Comment: Thanks aleroot. Actually i am not that good in sql. I tried this statement, but i was not successful.I am in the learning stage. If you don't mind, can you paste the complete statement here.

Comment: Change your group by clause adding the "Created_by" field as shown in my example, and remove the distinct clause near the select...

Comment: It worked for me. One last question here, I need all records from CSSC_QUALITY_DATA table. Can i use Right Join here? in the place of simple JOIN.